# Not able to write output to csv bs4 python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write the output of tha following code to a csv file. Data is getting overwritten. So at last I am able to see only last data that was scraped from the website in the output file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import re
import requests
for i in xrange(3179,7000):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://bvet.bytix.com/plus/trainer/default.aspx?id={}".format(i))
    except:
        continue
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        for eachuniversity in soup.findAll('fieldset',{'id':'ctl00_step2'}):
            data = i, re.sub(r'\s+',' ',''.join(eachuniversity.findAll(text=True)).encode('utf-8')),'\n'
    print data  
    myfile = open("ttt.csv", 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(data)
```

I am new to this. I do not know where I am wrong.

**UPDATE**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import re
import requests
with open("BBB.csv", 'wb') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for i in xrange(3179,7000):
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen("http://bvet.bytix.com/plus/trainer/default.aspx?id={}".format(i))
        except Exception:
            continue
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
            for eachuniversity in soup.findAll('fieldset',{'id':'ctl00_step2'}):
                data = [i] + [re.sub('\s+', '', text).encode('utf8') for text in eachuniversity.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: As a side note, if you fix this problem, you may well end up with an empty or incomplete file. When you `open` a file in write mode and never `close` it, it's up to Python and your OS to decide whether to flush any buffered-up data, and they may decide not to. (To make your life _really_ fun, they'll always flush when you're testing, and then stop flushing when you try to use the script for real.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file *once*, before looping, and add data to it in the loop as you find it:

```
with open("ttt.csv", 'wb') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for i in xrange(3179,7000):
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen("http://bvet.bytix.com/plus/trainer/default.aspx?id={}".format(i))
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            continue
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), from_encoding=page.info().getparam('charset'))
            for eachuniversity in soup.findAll('fieldset',{'id':'ctl00_step2'}):
                data = [i] + [re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip().encode('utf8') for text in eachuniversity.find_all(text=True) if text.strip()]
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Every time you open a file in `w` write mode, it is *truncated*. Any previous data is removed to make place for the new data you are about to write. The trick then is to open the file only once, at the start, and keep it open to write everything you need to while keeping it open.

The `with` statement here closes the file for you when the outer `for` loop is done.

The `from_encoding` passes any character set given by the server headers to `BeautifulSoup` so it won't have to guess as hard; for the given URL BeautifulSoup is actually guessing wrong if you don't add that keyword parameter.

I removed the newline you were adding to each row; the `csv.writer()` class takes care of newlines for you. I also changed the blanket `except:` to `except urllib2.HTTPError:` to catch *just* the exceptions that are actually being thrown here, not *everything*.

The text is cleaned up to write each text entry to separate columns.

This produces output like this:

```
"3179","Neue Suche starten","MoHaJa - die Schule für Hunde und Halter","Stähli Monika","Meisenweg 1","3303 Jegenstorf","Routenplaner","Ausbildung/Anerkennung: Triple-S Ausbildungszentrum für Mensch und Hund","Sprache: Deutsch","Tel.: +41 31 761 14 33","Handy: +41 79 760 41 69","info@hundeschule-mohaja.ch","www.hundeschule-mohaja.ch"
"3180","Neue Suche starten","Dogs Nature","Fernandez Salome-Nicole","Dorzematte 30","3313 Büren zum Hof","Routenplaner","Ausbildung/Anerkennung: Triple-S Ausbildungszentrum für Mensch und Hund","Sprache: Deutsch","Tel.: 079 658 71 71","info@dogsnature.ch","www.dogsnature.ch"
"3181","Neue Suche starten","Gynny-Dog","Speiser Franziska","Wirtsgartenweg 27","4123 Allschwil","Routenplaner","Ausbildung/Anerkennung: Triple-S Ausbildungszentrum für Mensch und Hund","Sprache: Deutsch","Handy: 076 517 20 94","franziska.speiser@gynny-dog.ch","www.gynny-dog.ch"
"3183","Neue Suche starten","keep-natural","Mory Sandra","Beim Werkhof","4434 Hölstein","Routenplaner","Ausbildung/Anerkennung: Triple-S Ausbildungszentrum für Mensch und Hund","Sprache: Deutsch","Tel.: 079 296 00 65","sandra.mory@keep-natural.ch","www.keep-natural.ch"
"3184","Neue Suche starten","Küng Silvia","Eptingerstrasse 41","4448 Läufelfingen","Routenplaner","Ausbildung/Anerkennung: Triple-S Ausbildungszentrum für Mensch und Hund","Sprache: Deutsch","Tel.: 061 981 38 04","Handy: 079 415 83 57","silvia.kueng@hotmail.com","www.different-dogs.ch"
```

Comment: Hi.. I was waiting for you. Thanks Martijin. I want to do little beautification. How do I comma separate the values properly? I tried doing something in `re.sub` line. It is getting messed up actually.

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by that; you want the text found in `eachuniversity` to be a set of columns in the output file?

Comment: Yes. exactly. Right now my output is one long thing in a single column in excel.

Comment: I am still not getting it correctly.. I guess some indentation problem. Still my output file is empty. I have written it in the same way as you have written

Comment: @Venky: What happens when you remove the `try:` and `except:` lines? E.g. run the `urlopen()` call without catching all exceptions?

Comment: I am getting `NameError: name 'uni' is not defined` now.. I dint remove the exception yet

Comment: @Venky: ah, my apologies, that was my local name for the test I was doing. Corrected. This also explains why I keep seeing the same line of data in the CSV. :-P

Comment: Why am I getting `unexpected indent in   writer.writerow(data)` line

Comment: @Venky: are you mixing tabs and spaces for indentation? Don't do that. Run the script with `python -tt` and fix any errors it finds.

Comment: I cleared the indetation problem. script does not have any error now. I removed the exception and tried. It wrote data for all valid URLs. But when I tried using exceptions, output file remains empty

Comment: @Venky: The code, as posted here, produces plenty of output for me, as shown in the answer. Make sure you didn't introduce another error by adding in the exception handling.

Comment: BTW. I am using Cygwin. and Does that have to do anything? and does MS office has anything to do with it?

Comment: I have updated the question. This is how I have written the code. I used tabs everywhere. It does produce output when I remove exceptions

Comment: @Venky: I've updated the code to only catch the HTTP exception, not everything else. The code, as posted, works for me. Using tabs is **not** recommended, btw. Use an editor that lets you configure it to use spaces for indentation instead.

Comment: @Venky: The code you posted works fine too. Do note it *takes a while* before data appears in that file! You are trying to open nearly 4000 requests, that *takes time*.

Comment: Is there anyway to see the progress of the script running? BTW it is now five minutes. still the file is empty

Comment: @Venky: no, not unless you add `print` statements to the script. It'll take a lot longer than 5 minutes. You can interrupt the program (CTRL-C) and it'll flush whatever it has to the file, but then you have to start over again.

Comment: @Venky: IIRC the file *remains* empty until it is closed, on Windows. On Mac and Linux you see data earlier, but Windows is not as friendly.

Comment: How do I close it? using f.close()?

Comment: @Venky: The file is closed *for* you by the `with` statement. You just have to be patient and wait for it to complete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41062/discussion-between-venky-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: It worked. I had to wait for the script to stop. It is writing them into the file. But why do we have to for the script to end in windows alone?

Answer (score 3):

It's getting overwritten because you're writing this inside the loop

```
 myfile = open("ttt.csv", 'wb')
```

Move that outside.

Comment: The `wr = csv.writer(…)` should _also_ be moved outside the loop. (It won't actually _break_ anything if left as-is, but it's not exactly good for readability.)

Answer (score 2):

Move this line:

```
myfile = open("ttt.csv", 'wb')
```

to before the `for` loop.  You're overwriting the file each time round the loop.